# How to handle lookups?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, lookup, lookup-tables

When I need to use a lookup I usually include the ID property in the view model class so I can use it this way in the corresponding view

```
<%= Html.LabelFor( model => model.LookupTableID )%>
<br />
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LookupTableID, Model.LookuptableList, new {}) %>
```

having `Model.LookuptableList` as a property in the Model itself like this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LookuptableList {
    get {
        return GetLookuptableList().Select(
            t => new SelectListItem { Text = t.Description, Value = t.LookupTableID.ToString() } );
    }
}
```

But I am not sure that this is a good way to handle this because of the function `GetLookuptableList()` inside the view model class.

is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Well, what is `GetLookuptableList()` then?  Why do you think it's problematic for that method to be in the model?

Comment: That function recovery the lookup list from the underlying store. I am not thinking it's problematic at all. I am just thinking that should'nt be there. Staying in the model does not properly follow separation of concerns....

Comment: Yes, Lorenzo. I think the access to underlying store from the view  model -Presentation layer- could be replaced with an IEnumerable member filled at controller level -Application layer-. so your viewModel could remain agnostic from the access to underlying store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including the entire look up table with every instance of the view model. A little overkill. I usually create a static utility class with the look up table that returns the `SelectListItem`.